# URL's not being resolved when in UserControl (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, resolve

If I pass the derived class `testA` a `PlaceHolder` that contains a  `Hyperlink`, with a url that starts with
 a tilde, it resolves it correctly.
 However, when I pass `testB`
 (identical apart from it inherits from
 `System.Web.UI.UserControl`) the same `PlaceHolder` It
 renders it literally (doesn't
 transform / resolve the '~')

Any ideas?

```
public class testA : System.Web.UI.Control
{
    public System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder plc { get; set; }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (plc != null)
            this.Controls.Add(plc);
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}


public class testB : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder plc { get; set; }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (plc != null)
            this.Controls.Add(plc);
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}
```

This is ASP.NET

Comment: Yes, if it didn't have runat=server then it wouldnt work in the System.Web.UI.Control

Comment: Thanks, now I see the difference (doh to me, thought they were the same)

Comment: Is the code that adds `testA` and `testB` to the page exactly the same?

Comment: Yes, i'm just changing the class testX inherits from and recompiling.

Comment: So you never call `LoadControl()` on `testX` when it inherits from `testB`?

Comment: @ Frédéric Hamidi, That's right, just instantiating it with a normal constructor.

Comment: Show us the pre-rendered markup.

Comment: @subt13 

<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server"><asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/foo.aspx">foo</a></asp:PlaceHolder>

Comment: @maxp, the closing tag of Hyperlink control is not correct, that may be the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you inherit from `System.Web.UI.UserControl` and do not associate your control with an `ascx` file then your control `TemplateSourceVirtualDirectory` will not be set, this is required by the `ResolveClientUrl` method - if its null or empty the url will be returned **AS IS**.

To solve your problem, just set `AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory` :

```
public class testB : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder plc { get; set; }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (plc != null)
        {
            this.AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory =
                    plc.AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory;
            this.Controls.Add(plc);
        }
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.aspx) is normally associated with an `ascx` file that defines its markup. Such controls should be instantiated using [TemplateControl.LoadControl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.loadcontrol.aspx) before they're added to the page, in order to perform event catch-up.

I suspect that event catch-up does not take place since you don't call `LoadControl()`, so the `Hyperlink`'s `NavigateUrl` never gets a chance to be properly resolved.

Comment: I was curious as to whether `testB` would work even when instantiated using `LoadControl(Type, object[])` and it doesn't.  Which is not too surprising, since as you point out, UserControls are meant to have associated .ascx and either be declared in the markup or loaded using LoadControl.